# FPDI character limitations

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdi

I am using FPDI to add names to a PDF. However I came across a issue, it will only allow me to add a maximum of 16 characters. Anything more and it will not display the name on the PDF. How can I resolve this? I wasn’t able to find anything with searching, and reading the limitations in the documentation. Thanks for any help/ suggestions.

```
 $pdf->SetXY($offset, 90);
 $pdf->Write(0, $cert['name']);
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: I added the code above.

Comment: There's not such a limitation. What the output of `var_dump($cert['name']);` ?